# jQuery - capturing LAST dynamic element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am adding new forms to my DOM dynamically, but the thing is that my code only captures first dynamically added element and not the **last** one.

This is my code. The screenshot below also explains everything.

Screenshot: [image]

```
$('#buildyourform').on('click', '.remove_dyn_summary', function() {
  var $txtarea = $(this).closest('b').find('.new_dyn_summary').val(); // this part is wrong
  alert($txtarea)
});
```

P.S. my business logic doesnt allow me to add incrementing numbers in classes or something.

`.last()` or `:last` didnt work for me I guess because elements were added dynamically.

I am probably missing something very simple..

Comment: is buildyourform dynamic?

Comment: Hello. Nope, fieldset #buildyourform is not dynamic

Comment: mate, reply fast. I think i may answer your question

Comment: Hello. Yes, field 1 is dynamic

Comment: Mind adding a fiddle?

Comment: In your screen shot, where is b.new_dyn_summary?

Comment: @Eimantas, are you done with the fiddle?

Comment: I am trying to find a way how to copy the dynamically added code :) just a min

Comment: @Eimantas right click on the node in developer toolbar and select copy as HTML, to copy dynamic parts.

Comment: @Eimantas, your "just a min" comments is now 10 mins ago ;)

Comment: I have already found out that way, but for some reason the dynamic html became unindented... So I am trying to make it readable for you guys

Comment: just put it. I'll intend it for you

Comment: OK, thank you! My javascript is at the bottom of js part. For some reason now it doesn't even capture the FIRST dynamic element in js fiddle :/ anyways: http://jsfiddle.net/3mU64/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use event delegation.

```
$(document).on('click','#buildyourform:last p.remove_dyn_summary', function() {
  var $txtarea = $(this).parent().prev().prev().children('textarea.new_dyn_summary').val(); 
  alert($txtarea);
});
```

Try the above.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It works for the first dybamic forms, but unfortunately when I click "ad new forms" again and then click the text it still captures the **first** dynamic form's value...

Comment: Edit: I did not pasted the code correctly, now it shows "undefined" :/

Comment: Thanks, now it finally worked! Could you please explain why my code did not work ? The reason is that I need to read more about DOM mapping with Jquery, right ?

Comment: You were looking for <b> which wasn't present.